# Ingesting particular sources into a particular rack

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, data-ingestion, bigdata

I have a cluster with three racks. For a set of particular sources I want to have them only being dumped into one rack so that I can monitor the traffic from that particular source to the other destinations. My question is simple. Is it possible to replicate a particular data source to one rack and the rest of the sources to all the other (two or three) racks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rack awareness is decided by a topology file. I don't think that you can achieve it by rack awareness settings.

Also, setting replication factor for a certain directory is not implemented yet.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-199